# Create one Record in a Week

Tags: workflow, record, unique-field

I want a workflow to validate the creation of only one record in a week. If more than one created within the same week, should show error. How should I do this?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Is this a standalone record? Or is it related to some parent object?

Comment: It is a standard record. Not related to any parent object.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use validation rules for this (as you can't query other existing records from validation rules).

What about this idea:

- create a new field 'week number' (text field, unique)
- create a workflow rule that fills the week number field by a formula, e.g.

  FLOOR( (Date__c -DATEVALUE("2006-01-01" ))/7)

This will make sure that only 1 record is allowed per week. If more are created, the uniqueness constraint is violated and you'll get an error.

If you need your week to start on another day, modify the startdate (2006-01-01) up or down.

---

Alternatively, you could create an apex trigger that queries the dates on existing records and checks that there is only 1 per week. This is a lot more complex, though, certainly if you don't have apex experience.

Here's an example of a similar trigger:
https://www.sfdcpanther.com/apex-trigger-to-prevent-duplicate-contact-record/

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you suggest me any way to achieve this through trigger?

Comment: It depends on the exact requirement. Do you want to check only against the latest record (check that it's 1 week or more ago) or against all records (checking that there's 1 week between all of the records).   Also, in general, you won't find people creating triggers for you on this site. You'll need to introduce yourself to APEX triggers or find a Salesforce partner that can help you with it.

Comment: Was trying the mentioned way : FLOOR( (Date__c -DATEVALUE("2006-01-01" ))/7) but got error massage in the workflow page: Error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type (Text).   Please help me with this.

Comment: Put TEXT() around the formula.